# gmail style file upload in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to implement Gmail style file upload in asp.net c#
where user will click on button and file dialog will open.
user selects a file,then process that file in code.
i dont want user to see file upload control he ll just click one button.
i have already used few solutions 
    example

```
 function OpenFileUpload() {

        var myFrame = document.getElementById('frameUpload');
        $(myFrame).focus();
        $(myFrame).contents().find("#FileUpload1").click();

        var value = $(myFrame).contents().find("#FileUpload1").val();
        if (value != '') {
            $(myFrame).contents().find("#btnSubmit").click();

        }


    }
```

need better solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you are talking about the server or client side....

File upload with large files is a interesting topic on it's own =)...especially large files...

find good articles here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

But why not use a convenient tool...

Here is good component:...
http://www.plupload.com/

HTH

Comment: i want to avoid using third party tools.. but i will check on ur urls

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like `swfupload` http://swfupload.org/

Like in Gmail case, it supports opening a file dialog by clicking on a link/button, it supports MULTIPLE selection of files and also can display the progress bar uploading the file.

Most of `SWFUpload` documentation uses PHP on the server side. Here is one example for ASP.NET ( [SWFUpload ASP.Net example site not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623778/swfupload-asp-net-example-site-not-working) ).

Please note that to support multiple selection of files to upload from a single window, this requires Flash, it cannot be done with standard input files.