# how to implement FILE UPLOAD as in UPDATE PANEL in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading

i have a mvc application to enter user profile to the system
i need to upload a image of user as well
but problem i face here is when i upload the image (calling functions in upload controller) all the data entered in other textboxes are gone.
what i need is when i click upload i want the image file to be saved(in a temp folder) and the remaining info in the textbox to remain intact. i have separate button to save the info to datbase which will save all data from TB and also the image(after converting it to byte array) to the databse

Comment: See my answer here on how to do uploads in asp.net mvc/c#
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412083/gmail-style-file-upload-in-c-sharp/9412244#9412244

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload file with pure AJAX. You need to create some iframe solution for that.